# Grouping values by date

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array that I get back from an SQL query and it looks like this when I do `print_r`:

```
Array([0]=>Array([id]=>1, [protein]=>20, [carbs]=>64, [date]=>2014-02-24), [1]=>Array([protein]=>1, [carbs]=>12, [score2]=>8, [date]=>2014-02-24), [2]=>Array([id]=>1, [protein]=>47, [carbs]=>84, [date]=>2014-02-25))
```

Now what I would like to do to this array is add up the carbs and protein values for each particular date. So take day `2014-02-24` I would like it for the `carb` and `protein` values to equal to `21` and `76`. So far I can access each individual value in a foreach loop but I am not sure how I can save these to a specific date. Here is the loop I am using:

```
foreach ($res as $row) {
   echo $row['protein'] . "<br />" . $row['carbs'] . "<br />" . $row['date'] . "<br />";
}
```

So obviously this doesn't give me the results I want but I am not sure how to group the information by a certain date, can someone explain how I can do this?

Comment: What you want is better done at the SQL query rather than with code.

Comment: @Prix I was just trying your answer it works only on one day. If you could post it again that would be helpful. I only proposed it on php because I have a rather complex SQL. It looks like this with your solution tell me if I have made an error. `SELECT SUM(protein) AS protein, SUM(carbs) AS carbs, date FROM tbl1 AS tb1 RIGHT JOIN tbl2 AS tb2 ON (tb1.e_id = tb2.e_id)LEFT JOIN tbl3 AS tb3 ON (tb2.m_id = tb3.m_id) WHERE tb1.date IN ("2014-02-27","2014-02-26","2014-02-25") AND tb1.user_id = 1`

Comment: Without further knowing how your data structure is on the database it would be hard to tell you but looking at all your joins it looks like your tables aren't well designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the array and add the totals for each carbs and protein to a variable or array representing each date to get the total for that date:

```
$grouped = array();
foreach($res as $row) {
    if(!array_key_exists($row['date'], $grouped)) // create array key if it doesnt exist
        $grouped[$row['date']] = array('protein' => 0, 'carbs' => 0);

    $grouped[$row['date']]['protein'] += $row['protein']; // sum for each date
    $grouped[$row['date']]['carbs'] += $row['carbs'];
}

print_r($grouped);
```

Example output:

```
Array(
    [2014-02-24] => Array(
        [protein] => 21
        [carbs] => 76
    )
    [2014-02-25] => Array(
        [protein] => 47
        [carbs] => 84
    )
)
```